Issue creating CSV from webscraping
I want to scrape this website https://www.thesoldiersproject.org/which-exo-members-are-in-the-military/ to retrieve the member name, enlisted date, and discharge date. But after I wrote and run my code below, it only saves the header into the CSV file.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Define the URL
url = "https://www.thesoldiersproject.org/which-exo-members-are-in-the-military/"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the content with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    # Find the relevant section containing the members' information
    content = soup.find('div', class_='entry-content')
    
    # Initialize a list to store the data
    data = []

    # Loop through the paragraphs and extract dates
    paragraphs = content.find_all('p')
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        text = paragraph.get_text()
        if 'Enlistment date:' in text and 'Discharge date:' in text:
            lines = text.split('\n')
            for line in lines:
                if 'Enlistment date:' in line and 'Discharge date:' in line:
                    parts = line.split(' - ')
                    if len(parts) == 2:
                        name = parts[0].strip()
                        enlistment_date = parts[1].split('Enlistment date: ')[1].split(',')[0].strip()
                        discharge_date = parts[1].split('Discharge date: ')[1].strip()
                        data.append([name, enlistment_date, discharge_date])
    
    # Convert the data into a pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Enlistment Date', 'Discharge Date'])
    
    # Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
    df.to_csv('exo_military_dates.csv', index=False)

else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the webpage. Status code:", response.status_code)

Expected output: the data that gets stored into the CSV file should contains member's name, member's enlisted date, and discharge date.

If there are no rows, then there is no data.  Is paragraphs empty? Or does 'Enlistment date:' in text and 'Discharge date:' in text evaluate to False? I'd add some print statements to your code to try to pinpoint the problem.

I guess I’m confused about why you need to scrape that information from this particular site? There are just eight people listed, in a free-form blog format which isn’t particularly amenable to web scraping; seems like something that would be very easy to extract by hand and very annoying (and fragile) to do with a script.

Thanks for the update; this is much better now. Though ideally, we'd like to see some debugging effort, too. Which of the conditions fails to be met, and why?

Tangentially, loading in Pandas just to write a CSV file at the end is huge overkill; Python ships with a compact and versatile csv module in its standard library (although it's slightly less polished than the support in Pandas)

I'd probably use regular expression to parse the enlistment/discharge dates:
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.thesoldiersproject.org/which-exo-members-are-in-the-military/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


def get_text(title):
    out, p = [], title.find_next_sibling("p")
    while p:
        out.append(p.text)
        p = p.find_next_sibling()
        if not (p and p.name == "p"):
            break
    return " ".join(out)


print(f"{'NAME':<20} {'START':<20} {'END':<20}")
print("-" * 62)
for h3 in soup.find_all(name="h3", string=re.compile(r"^\d+")):
    name = h3.text.split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
    text = get_text(h3)
    m = re.search(
        r"(?:enlisted|enlistment|started|began).*?(\S+ \d+, \d{4})(?:.*(?:discharge|back|finish).*?(\S+ \d+, \d+|\S+ \d{4}))?",
        text,
    )
    start, end = m[1], ("-" if not m[2] else m[2])
    print(f"{name:<20} {start:<20} {end:<20}")

Prints:
NAME                 START                END                 
--------------------------------------------------------------
Xiumin               May 7, 2019          December 6, 2020    
D.O                  July 1, 2019         January 25, 2020    
Suho                 May 14, 2020         February 14, 2022   
Chen                 October 26, 2020     April 25, 2022      
Chanyeol             March 29, 2021       September 2022      
Baekhyun             May 6, 2021          February 5, 2023    
Kai                  May 11, 2023         May 11, 2025        
Sehun                December 21, 2023    -                   


how can i do to change from "May 7, 2019", to "7-5-2019"?

@Zoeyyyy You can use datetime module to convert the string to dates and the format it, or pandas to create a dataframe and use pd.to_datetime() and then convert it to strings etc.

You should probably convert into machine-readable ISO 8601 dates rather than yet another brittle and ambiguous format.
